# QAbstractItemModel::removeRows does it cause memory leaks?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Suppose I have some code like this:

```
QListWidgetItem *pItem = new QListWidgetItem(...);
insertItem(i, pItem);
.....
then:
    removeRows(..)
```

If I don't delete the pointer `pItem`, will it cause memory leak?

Comment: If you need direct model manipulation, you need to work with `QListView` instead of `QListWidget`.

Answer (score 1):

From Qt documentation:

> If you need to insert a new item into the list at a particular position, then it should be constructed without a parent widget. The insertItem() function should then be used to place it within the list. The list widget will take ownership of the item.

So there is no memory leak.